# Extends Image class in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, image, module, kohana

I need to extends the class Image using iMagick of the module with the same name (https://github.com/kohana/image) but, I am not able to do it.

I want to add a new method call "cache".  This is what I'm trying to do:

classes/Image.php

```
abstract class Image extends Kohana_Image {}
```

classes/Kohana/Image.php

```
abstract class Kohana_Image {

    public function cache()
    {
        $this->_do_cache();
    }

    abstract protected function _do_cache();
}
```

classes/Kohana/Image/Imagick

```
class Kohana_Image_Imagick extends Image {

    protected function _do_cache()
    {
        // do something here
    }

}
```

This is how I Call the method:

```
Image::factory(DOCROOT.'/media/img/myimage.jpg')->cache();
```

This is the error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Image_Imagick::cache()
```

**Just to let you know, the iMagick is properly installed and works fine using the native Image class.**

Hope that you guys help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you read the documentation?](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Image#factory)

You must either:

Set `Image::$default_driver = 'Imagick';`

Or call it the `factory` specifying the driver to use:

```
Image::factory(DOCROOT.'/media/img/myimage.jpg', 'Imagick')->cache();
```

If you don't specify the driver to use Kohana falls back to whatever is set in `Image::$default_driver`

**OLD ANSWER**

You don't have the required class

```
// APPPATH./classes/Image/Imagick.php

class Image_Imagick extends Kohana_Image_Imagick {} // empty class
```

Then you should be able to call `Image_Imagick::cache`

If you want the method to be available from `Image`

```
// APPPATH./classes/Image.php

class Image extends Kohana_Image_Imagick {} // empty class
```

Now you can call `Image::cache`

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply.  yes, I have read the documentation. yes, i set the Image::$default_driver to "imagick".  I created the required classes and doesn't work either.